# Can't connect to ibm mq using jms

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I had a problem with connecting to the IBM MQ queue from Java. I tried to change the passwords for the service of the IBM MQ, create a connection without specifying a login and password, but nothing happens. I wrote the code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
    props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:/D:/JNDI/");

    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(props);
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup(connectionFactoryName);
        Destination destination = (Destination) initialContext.lookup(queueName);
        initialContext.close();

        Connection queueConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection("login", "password");// .createConnection();
```

which falls when I create a connection. I get an error:

> JMSWMQ2013: Invalid credentials were passed to the queue manager QueueManager 'QM_LOCAL' in the 'Client' connection mode using the host 'localhost (1414)'.
>   Verify that the provided user name and password are correct in the queue administrator that you are connecting to.

can I turn off the authentication so that the method ".createConnection();" works? If not, where do I set the password? I Use the Windows.

Thanks.

p.s.: I get the completion code '2' ('MQCC_FAILED'), reason'2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').

Comment: You need to look at the queue managers errors directory for a file called `AMQERR01.LOG`, this will show the reason for `2035`.

Comment: @JoshMc, I Can't find this file. In which package is it?

Comment: If you don't know the directory structure of MQ Server install then you should ask your MQAdmin for help.  There are at least 2 different AMQERR01.LOG files.  one for the entire MQ installation and one for each queue manager on the server.

Comment: On the server with the queue manager you would look in the `MQ_DATA_PATH/qmgrs/QM_LOCAL/errors` directory.  On unix/linux systems this is `/var/mqm/qmgrs/QM_LOCAL/errors`  on Windows it defaults to `C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM_LOCAL\errors`.  The env variable `MQ_DATA_PATH` should be set to the location so you can always echo that to see where it is located.

Comment: @JoshMc, I already checked this package, it does not have \qmgrs package

Comment: Make sure that you are as I stated looking "On the server with the queue manager".  If you are looking on your client you would not expect to find it.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a local manager on my PC